# How can I test ActionCable using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

This is my NotificationChannel

```
class NotificationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notification_user_#{user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

- How can I write test for this ActionCable channels

This is my Rspec

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative 'stubs/test_connection'

RSpec.describe NotificationChannel, type: :channel do

  before do
    @user = create(:user)
    @connection = TestConnection.new(@user)
    @channel = NotificationChannel.new @connection, {}
    @action_cable = ActionCable.server
  end

  let(:data) do
    {
      "category" => "regular",
      "region" => "us"
    }
  end

  it 'notify user' do
#error is in below line
    expect(@action_cable).to receive(:broadcast).with("notification_user_#{@user.id}")
    @channel.perform_action(data)
  end
end
```

when I run this spec it gives error

```
Wrong number of arguments. Expected 2, got 1
```

I used [this](https://gist.github.com/frankgu/7547f23446cfdcaf1aad66ea6cbc3971) link to write code for stub and this file.

Rails version - 5.0.0.1
Ruby version - 2.3.1

Comment: which line has the error ?

Comment: Error is in `expect(@action_cable)` line. I updated my question with comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expect(@action_cable).to receive(:broadcast).with("notification_user_#{@user.id}")
```

Looking closely broadcast needs two parameters so

```
expect(@action_cable).to receive(:broadcast).with("notification_user_#{@user.id}", data)
```

I cant guess what is going on however one issue is

```
  let(:data) do
    {
      "action" => 'action_name',
      "category" => "regular",
      "region" => "us"
    }
  end
```

You need an action for perform_action.
However you dont have any action defined in NotificationsChannel.

**Otherwise** you can try

```
NotificationChannel.broadcast_to("notification_user_#{@user.id}", data )
```

Comment: is `NotificationChannel.broadcast_to("notification_user_#{@user.id}", data )` equivalent to `expect(@action_cable).to receive(:broadcast).with("notification_user_#{@user.id}")
    @channel.perform_action(data)`

OR we can only use this if we have an action defined but in my case there is only `subscribed` and `unsubscribed`  and what about `unsubscribed`

Comment: I updated my answer regarding the error. Perform_action is meant to be called (by the framework automatically) when you do perform from javascript to call an action on channel. broadcast_to is to broadcast a message to subscribers eg: "notification_user_#{user.id}"