# How do I test an ActionCable connection?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

How do I write a test for an ActionCable `Connection` in RSpec? I've found [documentation](https://relishapp.com/palkan/action-cable-testing/docs) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227773/how-can-i-test-actioncable-channels-using-rspec) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293150/how-can-i-test-actioncable-using-rspec) about testing `Channel`s, but I'm having a hard time finding information about testing `Connection`s.

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549428/how-to-test-actioncable-along-with-devise-using-rspec), which links to [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing/issues/26#issuecomment-392481619) showing a potential technique. However, I'm not sure whether that's a sane pattern I want to use in my own code.

Comment: What is "not sane" about it?

Comment: @lacostenycoder The test is set up as `type: :channel`. I'm nervous that's using some RSpec/Rails magic meant to make `Channel` tests more easier to write but isn't helpful specifically for working with a `Connection`.

Comment: I guess without seeing what exactly it is you're testing for, I can't comment further on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [action-cable-testing gem](https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing) includes support for testing `Connection`s. Here's the documentation: https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing#rspec-usage

And here's the RSpec example given in the documentation:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ApplicationCable::Connection, type: :channel do
  it "successfully connects" do
    connect "/cable", headers: { "X-USER-ID" => "325" }
    expect(connection.user_id).to eq "325"
  end

  it "rejects connection" do
    expect { connect "/cable" }.to have_rejected_connection
  end
end
```